# Programmatic (as opposed to link-based) navigation in jQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, navigation

The problem has been discussed several times, but I am yet to see a concrete answer.

Similar/same question : [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820548/jquery-mobile-requesting-multi-page-page-via-changepage)

Suppose that I have `index.html`:

```
    <div id="index1" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header"><h1>Index 1</h1></div>
            <div data-role="content"></div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <a data-role="button" id="toshop2">
                    To Shop 2
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and `shop.html`:

```
<div id="shop1" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>Shop 1</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <a data-role="button" href="#shop2">To Shop 2</a>
            <a data-role="button" href="index.html" rel="external">
                To Index
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="shop2" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header"><h1>Shop 2</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content"></div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <a data-role="button" href="#shop1">To Shop 1</a>
            <a data-role="button" href="index.html" rel="external">
                To Index
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I want to do something like:

```
$('#toshop2').on('click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("shop.html#shop2");
});
```

which, as we all know by now, won't work. It'll grab the first DOM page (`#shop1` out of `shop.html` and append it into `index.html` DOM.

I know that something silly like:

```
$('#toshop2').on('click', function() {
    window.open('shop.html#shop2', '_parent');
});
```

would work (yes, there won't be a transition).

Questions are (*assuming there is no other solution, but to hack*):

1. Can I/should I hack it differently?
2. Can I somehow still get transition to an external page?

Answer (score 0):

You can request the external document manually and then only insert the portion that you want to the DOM:

```
//delegate event handler binding to links with a custom class
//(any link that links to a pseudo-page in an external document
$(document).delegate('.my-external-links', 'click', function () {

    //get the location of the external document and the requested page (hash)
    var theHREF   = this.href,
        theTarget = '#shop1';
    if (theHREF.indexOf('#') > -1) {
        theTarget = '#' + theHREF.split('#')[1];
        theHREF   = theHREF.split('#')[0];
    }

    //first see if this page is already in the DOM, if so just navigate to it
    if ($(theTarget).length) {
        $.mobile.changePage($(theTarget));
        return;
    }

    //show the loading spinner
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    //do AJAX request to get new pages into the DOM
    $.ajax({
        url : theHREF,
        success : function (response) {

            //hide the loading spinner
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

            //find all the `data-role="page"` elements and add them to the DOM
            $(response).find('[data-role="page"]').appendTo('body');

            //now navigate to the requested page which should be in the DOM
            $.mobile.changePage($(theTarget));
        },
        error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /*don't forget to handle errors*/ }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I'm pretty sure there is a plugin for this as well, but as you can see it's not that much code or complication.

Comment: I may have not been clear. I meant that I don't want to insert the external HTML page into the DOM. I want to simulate programmtically what would amount to `<a href="shop.html#shop2" rel="external"></a>`

Comment: That's what I did. First you get all the `data-role="page"` elements from the external document, then you add them to the current DOM (you have to do this because jQuery Mobile will ignore all but the first pseudo-page in a document), then you can navigate to them. And this is all done just by adding a class to the links that you want to exhibit this behavior. Basically you can just pull-in the content that you want from the external document but you might as well load all of the pages so you don't have to create another HTTP request. See the **update** regarding pages already in the DOM.

Comment: I have to say, I don't quite get why you need to put more than one pseudo-page into an external document. Why not just create an external document for each page?

Comment: Because each external HTML represents a mini-application, with its own JS, multiples inner pages and whatnot. I don't want to **pull** a page. I want to load the entire HTML file. I understand that it may not be the "JQM way", but I was merely asking for a "prettier hack". And AFAIK what you describe doesn't simulate the `rel=external"` anchor I mentioned

Comment: You cannot take advantage of the page-animations if you do this. You've got to do a full-page-refresh (if you don't want to use a solution like the one I provided). Why not put each pseudo-page in it's own document and then split-up the sections into folders? You can use includes to reference global or section-wide assets.

Comment: If you look at my question - I clearly state that I understand there may not be animation. HTML page for each small section is barely a solution. I would like to have shop with inner sections, support with inner sections... just as an example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9699/discussion-between-zenmaster-and-jasper)

Comment: Well your site structure is certainly up-to-you. I'm just pointing-out how to do what you want within jQuery Mobile. I know when I started that trying to use multiple pseudo-pages in external documents seemed easy but in the end I dumped the idea since it just creates unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try to use changepage twice?

```
$.mobile.changePage( "shop.html", { transition: "none"} );
$.mobile.changePage( "#shop2", { transition: "slideup"} );
```

or just use loadPage to load the shop.html into DOM in background and change to #shop2 after?

```
$.mobile.loadPage( "shop.html" );
$.mobile.changePage( "#shop2", { transition: "slideup"} );
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know. I suspect that I would have to disconnect `hashChange` at the very least (as parameter to `changePage`).